# Ошибка при миграции моделей в django

Tags: django, sqlite, консоль

Тут такая ситуация , уже третью базу данных dbsqlite снес.Ничего не помогает. и Журнал чистил

1. Ввожу `python manage.py migrate` # сработало
2. Создаю суперпользователя `python manage.py createsuperuser` # сработало
3. Ввожу команду чтобы заработал блог `manage.py makemigrations` # сработало
4. Ввожу `python manage.py migrate` # ошибка

Делаю подругому

1. Ввожу команду чтобы заработал блог `manage.py makemigrations` # сработало
2. Ввожу `python manage.py migrate` # сработало
3. Создаю суперпользователя `python manage.py createsuperuser` # А теперь ошибка вылечает и не создается супер юзер(((

```py
from django.db import models  # модуля импортируем модели

"""
Тут описывается, как должны выглядеть наши таблицы в базе данных
====================================================================
Свойства, которое описано в классе будут столбцами в таблицах базы данных
"""

class Category(models.Model):
    """Модель категорий"""
    """из модуля находим класс и наследуемся от него"""
    """создаем свойство класса, который создаст столбец таблицы в БД для имени и url"""
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="имя", max_length=140)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="url", max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        """Прописываем метод, чтобы в админ панели выводилось распечатку объекта"""
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        """Этот метод меняет название класса в админ части сайта"""
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        """название класса в множественном числе"""
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'


class Tag(models.Model):
    """Модель Тэгов"""
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="имя", max_length=140)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="url", max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Тег'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Теги'


class Post(models.Model):
    """Модель Постов"""
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Заглавие", max_length=500)
    mini_text = models.TextField(verbose_name="краткое содержание")
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='полное содержание', max_length=10000000)
    created_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='дата создания', auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='url', max_length=100, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='категория', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, verbose_name='тэг', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Пост'
        verbose_name_plural='Посты'


class Comment(models.Model):
    """Модель комментариев"""
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, verbose_name='статья', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='текст комментария')
    created_date = models.DateField('дата создания')
    moderation = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Комментарий'
        verbose_name_plural='Комментарии'
```

Comment: Какая именно ошибка, мы сами должны угадать?

Comment: дружище спасибо за ответ ,я уже решил, Был трейсбек, который срабатывал из за того что pycharm был подключен к базе данным